# 'staticmethod' Object has no attribute 'short_description'

Tags: django, django-admin, pylint

I am writing a very normal django admin class with custom action like this:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ("enable", "disable")

    def enable(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)
    enable.short_description = _("Enable selected items")

    def disable(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=False)
    disable.short_description = _("Disable selected items")
```

Now pylint complain that `self` has not been used in `enable` and `disable`  and that these methods can be functions (or staticmethod)

adding `@staticmethod` decorator however causes django to give error.

> AttributeError: 'staticmethod' object has no attribute 'short_description'

And my question is, how do I make both django and pylint happy?

Comment: Just suppress the pylint warning with an inline comment.

Comment: That's not the solution though. I don't want to suppress pylint

Comment: Why not? It's clearly wrong in this case, but you probably don't want to suppress that message in your `.pylintrc` as there may be other cases that it detects correctly.

Comment: I am using `pylint_django` which supposedly deal with that magic thing and usually I have no problem with pylint. only this case

Comment: Then: 1. ***mention that* in your question**; 2. if you think that package is not working, raise an issue with the maintainers; and 3. in the meantime suppress (or just ignore) the warning, that *is* the (maybe temporary) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this question,however,i read django code.You can read django.contrib.admin.options #1270, We define a admin func is not a "real" method of class,django code use `self.get_actions(request)[action][0]` to get your function, then,use  `func(self, request, queryset)` to run it ,so, you can not use `@staticmethod` to solve pylint warning.

Comment: Please format this answer in a better way, not just inline codes but with the whole code block.